# Angular truncates HTTP request URL's on a opening parentheses

Tags: http, url, angular

I'm running into a problem with HTTP request's being truncated when a opening parentheses exists with one of the query string param values.

This is an example of the request I'm trying to make.

> HTTP GET
>   http://localhost:8888/v1/clients?agencyId=120&name=Bridgewater Community Healthcare NHS Foundation Trust (#1234)&ownerType=client&ownerId=1234

However, the request fails with 400 bad request due to the above URL being truncated to the following.

> http://localhost:8888/v1/clients?agencyId=120&name=Bridgewater%20Community%20Healthcare%20NHS%20Foundation%20Trust%20(

Any idea why Angular would be truncating my URLs?

**EDIT:** *As pointed out it's the hashtag that Angular is truncating... but why, why isn't the angular library URL encoding the hashtag when it clearly encodes other chars e.g. spaces*

Comment: It breaks on the `#` which should be percent encode to %23  (`#` is a fragment identifier)

Comment: I understand how hash fragment are used etc. but I don't understand why angular is not URL encoding the hash fragment?